# C# input array is longer than the number of columns after using removeAt

Tags: c#, datatable

I am well aware that after explicitly remove a column from the datatable will result in this issue when attempted to merge ZRP and 08-0729-01-MAR, therefore is there anyway to remove the column without getting the exception? Please help

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string filepath = @"C:\Users\2563911\source\repos\test.txt";
        using (System.IO.TextReader tr = File.OpenText(filepath))
        {
            string line;

            while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (!line.StartsWith("-"))
                {
                    if (line.Length < 82 || line.Contains("MY01"))
                    {

                        string[] items = line.Replace("MY01", "").Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                        try
                        {
                            if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
                            {
                                // Create the data columns for the data table based on the number of items
                                // on the first line of the file
                                for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
                                {
                                    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column" + i, typeof(string)));

                                }
                             }

                            dt.Rows.Add(items);


                            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                            {
                                dr[2] = dr[1].ToString() + dr[2].ToString();
                            }
                            dt.Columns.RemoveAt(1);                                
                        }

                        catch (System.ArgumentException c)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(c.Message);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //show it in gridview
            this.DataGridView.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Text file:

MY01 CISCO ZPRP 08-0729-01-MAR 08-0729-01
MY01 CISCO ZPRP 08-0729-01-MAR 08-0729-01
MY01 CISCO ZPRP 08-0729-01-MAR 08-0729-01
MY01 CISCO ZPRP 10-2919-01$1

Comment: Use `DataRow row = dt.NewRow()` and populate `row`.  You will have to explicitly set values for the columns you care about, but it will definitely avoid this exception.

Comment: You should do `dt.Columns.RemoveAt(1)` after while loop is completed